# Create pluggable component in Preact

Tags: reactjs, preact

I've started working with preact to create a pwa with a smaller footprint. All's going well till now and the app is almost done as a modular component.

The trouble in paradise occurred when I tried to plug this component inside another react web app. The preact component simply renders on the word go. Whereas I want to instantiate this component in my own view hierarchy.

Something like:

```
<div className={'abcd'}>
  <PreactComponent />
</div>
```

But as soon as I try to include the `bundle.js` from Preact's build, it renders to `body` wiping away everything else.

Is there something I am missing?

This is the `Preact` `index.js`

```
import { h, render, Component } from 'preact';
import './style';
import App from './components/app';

export default class Player extends Component {
  render() {
    let bucketId = this.props.bucketId
    let videoId = this.props.videoId
    return <App pluggedIn={true} />
  }
}
```

Ideally, this should have given me a component `<Player/>` but it's rendering on its own. I am not even using `Preact.render()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you build your bundle.js using [preact-cli](https://github.com/developit/preact-cli)?  Right now preact-cli is mainly targeted at building Progressive Web Apps, not bundles for use in other codebases (it is not a general-purpose bundler).  You aren't invoking preact.render(), but the CLI actually wraps your component in a render call and some other stuff like polyfills in order to improve the experience and reduce boilerplate.

I believe if you really wanted to use preact-cli to build a bundle for consumption by another app (though not likely React, since that's not really possible at all right now), you could create a `preact.config.js` that does this:

```
export default config => {
  config.output.library = 'myLibName';
  config.output.libraryTarget = 'umd';
}
```

But honestly I wouldn't recommend it. The CLI is quite specifically built for creating PWA's, which is not the setup you're going for here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes I used `preact-cli`. Can you please tell me how to build this as a component? I don't want to build this component in react.